# Nginx, rewrite and enabling escaped characters

Tags: nginx

I use redirect for all requests from /api/ route to my server (port 5000).
Here is my nginx.conf:

```
location /api/ {
  rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ /$1 break;
  proxy_pass  http://100.100.100.100:5000;#my ip here
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

nginx decodes all escaped characters but I need original version. How to change my nginx.conf?

Comment: The only way is not to use `rewrite`, but your server will get request with `/api/` prefix. The best way is not to relay on escaping preservation

Comment: Alexey, but how to do it without rewrite?

Comment: Just remove rewrite

Comment: Also without an explicit rewrite rule, nginx will convert escape characters. See answer below for a solution that actually works. When nginx maps a variable, it does not convert escape characters.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite without touching escape characters can be achieved using `map` and `$request_uri` variable:

```
map $request_uri $request_uri_api {
  ~^/api/(.*)  $1;
}

location /api/ {    
  proxy_pass  http://100.100.100.100:5000/$request_uri_api;
}
```